# "Unexpected token ." JSON Parse Fails to Parse Decimal with Leading Zero

Tags: javascript, sql, json, parsing, oracle11g

I am trying to parse data from an Oracle 11g db.  Many of the columns I have set up contain decimal values with a leading zero (0.1, 0.99,...). The column data format is NUMBER(10,2) and performing a basic query on the data within SQL Developer shows the leading zero.

When trying to call JSON.Parse, I get an error of "Unexpected token ."

I'm assuming JSON.Parse does not recognize the leading zero. If I convert the data type to string when I perform the initial query prior to JSON.Parse, I don't have any problems.  I am trying to avoid this however, because it means I will have to do a type conversion at a later point to perform calculations on the data.

Here is a working example of the data format using TO_CHAR() prior to parsing:

```
{"row":[{"PERCENT_WORK_COMPLETE":"   0.99", -- Requires TO_CHAR b/c of leading zero. Fails without conversion.
         "FINISH_VARIANCE":-242,            --Number with no conversion. This works because there are no values containing decimals with leading zero.
}]}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to retain the Number data type and still be able to use JSON.Parse?  I see that JSON.Parse has a "Reviver" argument... JSON.parse(text[, reviver])  I'm not sure how I might be able to use this to do what I'm trying to accomplish.  Help is appreciated.

***EDIT***

The example object shown above is stored as a variable called ajaxResponse.

```
console.log("ajaxResponse", ajaxResponse); --this is what I am using to display the above example.
```

This is how I am trying to parse the data:

```
jsonobj = JSON.parse(ajaxResponse);
```

In the example above, the "PERCENT_WORK_COMPLETE" column has been converted to a string prior to running JSON.Parse.  The "FINISH_VARIANCE" column has been left as a number.  This works.

However, if I do not convert "PERCENT_WORK_COMPLETE" to a string (i.e. leave it as 0.99, not "   0.99"), the parsing fails.

Looking at the object after running JSON.Parse, with the above example, my object contains a string value for "PERCENT_WORK_COMPLETE" and a number value for "FINISH_VARIANCE", as I'd expect.

Comment: What is the exact string that you're passing to `parse()`?

Comment: `JSON.parse` has no problems with numbers with leading zeros. This can be readily verified right from your browser's debug console.

Comment: Works on my end `JSON.parse('{"row":[{"PERCENT_WORK_COMPLETE":"   0.99","FINISH_VARIANCE":-242}]}')`

Comment: You should post the actual JSON that's causing the error. Posting only the JSON that *doesn't* cause the error really doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I convert the data type to string when I perform the initial query prior to JSON.Parse, I don't have any problems.

That's because `JSON.parse()` expects a string, and not an object. I assume that you used the JSON directly, something like this (in PHP):

```
var data = <?= json_encode(someData) ?>

//which would end up like this, a direct object
var data = {"foo":"bar"};

//instead of a string
var data = '{"foo":"bar"}';
```

Using the former instead of the latter will throw a parse error. You can verify by doing the following in the console:

```
JSON.parse({"foo":"bar"})    // will fail
JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar"}')  // will return an object
```

> it means I will have to do a type conversion at a later point to perform calculations on the data.

If you expect some data to be a number but is currently a string, then you can do a simple `+` to convert it.

```
var number = +"   0.99" //number === 0.99
```

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's a pretty straightforward conversion. I was just trying to determine if there was a way to maintain the integer during the parsing process.

Comment: @thefreeline Nothing is wrong with a leading `0` for a number. `JSON.parse('{"foo":0.99}')` works. There must be something wrong with the JSON data, which you can check with JSON validators.